# Unity Смена направления прыжка

Tags: unity3d

Вопрос в следующем.
Есть код прыжка персонажа в длину, при наступлении на Collider игрок меняет направление на 90 градусов, но при прыжке так же прыгает в первоначальную сторону.

Что в такой ситуации можно сделать?

Фрагмент кода отвечающий за прыжок

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Force += 0.1f;
            ForceForward += 1;
        }
        if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            if (Force >= MaxForce)
            {
                Force = MaxForce;
            }
            MyRb.velocity = new Vector2(Time.deltaTime*ForceForward, Force);
            Debug.Log(Force);
            Force = 0;
            ForceForward = 100;
        }
```

Сам поворот делаю так

```
transform.Rotate(0, -90, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Решено, Использовал

```cs
MyRb.velocity = new Vector3(Time.deltaTime*ForceForward, Force);
```

и `bool`, если `bool == true`, то получаем это

```cs
MyRb.velocity = new Vector3(0, Force, Time.deltaTime*ForceForward);
```